# Specify different python version for library // RobotFramework

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, robotframework

I'm using a proprietary library for traffic generator that working only in 2.7.5-32bit. My system is ubuntu-64bit and all other components are using installed python 2.7.6 (64bit). 
Is there any way to configure explicitly for this library to use another version of python?

Comment: You can use a `virtualenv` to manage a particular environment, including a specific interpreter and appropriate add-ins.

Comment: may you specify some more info please?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Internet for those terms? There are plenty of tutorials etc already.

Comment: yes, i did, thanks for your help, not what i'm looking for. Need to explicitly to work with only one library with different interpreter.

Comment: So install that one library in a virtual environment based on that specific interpreter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to solve it, it's running Remote Library on virtual machine or on other network device.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple versions of python when running a test -- a test runs as a single process.

The only work-around is to run this other library as a server process and access it remotely through the [remote library interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface).